# Dynamic Graph Generation using dagre-d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, dagre-d3

I want to generate a graph which takes input from json model. I am using dagre-d3.js. I am able to generate nodes and also able to connect nodes statically. The method graph.addEdge(null,"A","B") connects two nodes. But i want to create edges dynamically. Is there any way to generate graph in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the [interactive demo](http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/interactive-demo.html).
More code examples can also be found [here](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/wiki).